# Is it okay/good practice to cite other answers just after publishing your own?

Tags: discussion, answers, editing

Sometimes it takes time to write a (hopefully) good answer: you have to search for references, for the exact wording of rules on manuals, looking for the description of a particular magic item, etc.

It happens to me that while I am writing my answer, someone else answers the question, coming up with very similar ideas and/or interpretation as mine and so on. I realize this only once my own answer is published: usually I decide to edit my own answer and cite the other ones, for sake of completeness, maybe commenting about them or adding other details.

I am wondering if this is good practice, or if is it better to leave my answer as it is without referring to other answers.

Comment: Why wouldn't this be okay? What kinds of problems/downsides do you foresee happening as a result of this?

Comment: Some related posts: "[What is the best way to deal with duplicate answers which reference each other?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9838)" and "[Should I update my answer with information from someone else's answer?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9497)" and "[Should I be requesting people answer the question independently?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3326)"

Comment: @V2Blast Because I received some downvotes on an answer and when I asked if someone could provide a couple of comments on it, some users pointed out that maybe citing other answers are not well considered.

Comment: @Eddymage Not to blow up your spot, but I find that looking at specifics generally helps, are you talking about [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/174756/can-i-use-a-gauntlet-as-an-arcane-focus/174762#174762) of yours?

Comment: @Rubiksmoose That one made me wonder if citing other answers is a good practice in general. Under that one I received some comments explaining other "problems" rather than citing in my answer, hence now I am interested in the general practice.

Comment: @Eddymage Understood. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I do; if another answer indicates something I hadn’t thought of, forgot, or otherwise didn’t include (or wasn’t planning to include) in my answer, that I think is valuable and worthwhile, I’ll link to their answer.

I’ll also summarize the take-away from their answer, because in theory that answer could get deleted, and internal link rot is just as bad as external link rot. Of course, there is no risk of my answer being a link-only answer, since I’m not doing this when I don’t have more to add—if another answer already answers the question fully and completely, I upvote it, not write another redundant answer.

I don’t do it when I feel that my answer (or the answer I was planning to write) already covered the material in their answer. Answers going over the same ideas in different language can have value, so it’s not a problem, but there’s less call for a link in that case.